# Why didn't Scatter Gather Browsing meet great adoption in data applications?

Tags: clustering

I am currently writing a thesis about the Scatter Gather document browsing method by Doug Cutting (1993) and I was wondering, why it didn't get adopted in big information applications? It is a great and fun way of browsing documents and it dawned on me that it hasn't meet the success that it merits.

EDIT:

The paper is called:

> Scatter/Gather: A Cluster-based Approach to Browsing Large Document
>   Collections

Simply put, S-G is a document browsing method that uses clustering at its core. A document collection is clustered into a few clusters (say `k=10`), and a label is generated for each of them. Then the user is presented with the labels and makes a selection of m clusters (`m < k`). Afterwards the documents from the `m` clusters get gathered and re-clustered to `k` clusters again. The `k` clusters get labeled again and then presented again to the user. The process finishes when there are no more clusters left, only individual documents.

Comment: Can you summarize the method, or at least give full bibliographical details? That would make it easier for us to know what you are talking about.

Comment: I am not an expert in information retrieval (IR) but skim-reading the paper [here](http://lucene.sourceforge.net/papers/sigir92.ps) (PostScript sorry) appears that it is a hybrid $k$-means/agglomerative approach; the clustering effectively creates a table of contents for the collection of documents. This seems indeed elegant but implementation is big issue in IR methods. Early 2000's was a time that matrix factorisation method like NNMF and incremental SVD took off. So.. I suspect that simply put... it wasn't cool and/or competitive enough to get enough people on board? (+1 @Stephan's comment)

Comment: @StephanKolassa  I edited my post - ty for your answers

Comment: @usεr11852 thank you for your insight. I think you are right that S-G was overshadowed from other technologies at the time.